# Python Numpy make a pattern with a square matrix of any dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am having difficulties trying to generate a specific pattern that would work for any square matrix with any square dimension using NumPy

*For example:*

User input: **n = 3**

Output:

```
[[1 2 0]
 [2 3 2]
 [0 2 1]]
```

User input: **n = 5**

Output:

```
[[1 2 3 0 0]
 [2 3 4 0 0]
 [3 4 5 4 3]
 [0 0 4 3 2]
 [0 0 3 2 1]]
```

User input: **n = 8**

Output:

```
[[1 2 3 4 5 0 0 0]
 [2 3 4 5 6 0 0 0]
 [3 4 5 6 7 0 0 0]
 [4 5 6 9 8 7 6 5]
 [5 6 7 8 9 6 5 4]
 [0 0 0 7 6 5 4 3]
 [0 0 0 6 5 4 3 2]
 [0 0 0 5 4 3 2 1]]
```

Since a square matrix can be generated with any number in the form of (n x n), there would be instances where the user input is an odd number, how would I start figuring out the equations needed to make this work?

---

*I got this going on but I was only able to do it on one corner of the matrix, any suggestion or idea is appreciated, thank you!*

```
def input_number(n):
    matrix = np.zeros(shape=(n, n), dtype=int)

    for y in range(round(n // 2) + 1):
        for x in range(round(n // 2) + 1):
            matrix[y, x] = x + y + 1
        y += 1
```

Input: **n = 4**

Output:

```
[[1 2 3 0 0]
 [2 3 4 0 0]
 [3 4 5 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I looked around a bit more and was eventually able to pull it off, here's my take on it.**

```
import numpy as np


def input_number(n):
    matrix = np.zeros(shape=(n, n), dtype=int)

    for y in range(round(n // 2) + 1):
        for x in range(round(n // 2) + 1):
            matrix[y, x] = y + x + 1
            matrix[(n - y) - 1][(n - x) - 1] = matrix[y, x]

    print(matrix)


input_number(n)
```

Input: **3**

Output:

```
[[1 2 0]
 [2 3 2]
 [0 2 1]]
```

Input: **5**

Output:

```
[[1 2 3 0 0]
 [2 3 4 0 0]
 [3 4 5 4 3]
 [0 0 4 3 2]
 [0 0 3 2 1]]
```

Input: **8**

Output:

```
[[1 2 3 4 5 0 0 0]
 [2 3 4 5 6 0 0 0]
 [3 4 5 6 7 0 0 0]
 [4 5 6 9 8 7 6 5]
 [5 6 7 8 9 6 5 4]
 [0 0 0 7 6 5 4 3]
 [0 0 0 6 5 4 3 2]
 [0 0 0 5 4 3 2 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def foo(n):
    half = (n+1) // 2
    res = np.zeros((n, n), int)
    res[:half, :half] = np.arange(1, 1 + half) + np.arange(half).reshape(half, 1)
    res[n//2:, n//2:] = res[half-1::-1, half-1::-1]
    return res
```

This creates the top-left quarter then mirrors it to the bottom-right quarter.

Note it behaves a little differently to your example of n=8, the output is:

```
  [[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5, 4, 3],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 3, 2],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

But I'll leave it this way because it seems more logical...you can edit the code if needed to make the center 4 values mix with each other as you showed.

Comment: Wow I didn't think about that, mirroring the corner to the opposite one seems to work but yeah, I'm working on a way to make the middle like shown in the example

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the pattern of zeros in these examples. In the cases of n=3 and n=5 the zero subarrays in the corners are of the size (n//2)x(n//2), but for n=8 they are of the size 3x3 and not 4x4. Assuming that the size of these subarrays should be (n//2)x(n//2) the following code should work:

```
n = 7
A = np.zeros((n, n), dtype=int)
for i in range(n):
    A.ravel()[i:(n-i)*n:n+1] = n-i
m = n//2
A[:m, :m] = 0
A[-m:, -m:] = 0
A = A + A.T - np.diag(np.diag(A))
A = A[:, ::-1]
```

If the zero subarrays should be smaller, it suffices to change the value of `m`.

Comment: There may be another pattern along with (n//2)x(n//2), as the middle area of the 8x8 matrix seems to be following their own pattern as well.